# Cross-platform way of retrieving GPS position on mobile devices?

Tags: mobile, cross-platform, gps

I'm planning to write a small app that should work on at least the popular smartphone devices, but would like (if possible) to write it only once for all platforms (using something like jQuery Mobile).

Is there any way to retrieve (to within at least street-level accuracy) the current GPS position of a mobile device, without writing custom code for each possible platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're programming natively, you're out of luck. Apple iOS and Android are very different beasts. Your best bet would be a browser application. The geolocation API is standardized: http://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/